# NSMutableArray with init and mutableCopy, how to autorelease?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, autorelease

I've gone crazy trying to find a leak with an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *mutablearray =[[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: array] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Finally I understood that I need to autorelease twice my mutablearray because initWithArray is +1 and mutableCopy is +1 too.

Then I'm doing:

```
NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: array] autorelease];
mutablearray = [[mutablearray mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

But, it's correct to do?:

```
NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [[[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: array] autorelease] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of creating an `NSMutableArray`, making a mutable copy, and throwing away the original **mutable** object? You really don't need to make a mutable copy of a mutable object. Use `[array mutableCopy]`, or `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array]`. One or the other. Not both.

Comment: Sure you are right, but I'm doing it because I remember some problems in the past trying to take an Array from NSUserDefaults

`NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [userDefaults objectForKey:@"KEY"]] autorelease];`@PartiallyFinite Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Can't you just use `[[userDefaults objectForKey:@"KEY"] mutableCopy]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question comes in mind is WHY you are initializing and also making a mutable copy at the same time initWithArray gives a new instance with new memory and you can use it.Then why creating a mutable copy of it?

Use

```
NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: array]autorelease];
```

This gives you a mutable instance .So no need for calling mutablecopy anyway

OR

```
NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [[array mutableCopy]autorelease];
```

Comment: Sure you are right, but I'm doing it because I remember some problems in the past trying to take an Array from NSUserDefaults

`NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [userDefaults objectForKey:@"KEY"]] autorelease];`